# Scheduler to switch things on/off based on weekday, date and time of day

Tags: linux, time, scheduler

I'm looking for a Linux program that can give me an on/off answer based on time. I'm thinking of something that can read simple rules like these

```
mon-wed 18:30-21:15
thu     17:30-21:15
fri     14:00-17:00
2016.10.10 10:00-13:00
```

and give me a nonzero exit status when the current time is not in any of the ranges. Is there a program that does this?

Background: I want to keep open an electric door lock during certain times of the day. I started to program the functionality when I thought "somebody must have done this!" I can't seem to find anything though. A library with matching functionality would be welcome too.

Comment: `man 5 crontab`

Comment: Cron is not suitable. I would have to write two rules, one for turning on and one for turning off. Neither Cron nor Anacron have a concept of ranges so they wouldn't know whether they still have to open the door when the device was off. Plus Cron syntax is full of pitfalls, I don't want to write my rules in that syntax.

Comment: crontab runs in every minute. This is enough small interval after power on the device. Crontab has ranges, read the fine manual!

Comment: Assume that `/bin/lock-open` and `/bin/lock-close` exist to operate the lock. Now please try to encode the above rules as crontab entries and I think you will see why I consider Cron unsuitable. I've considered doing it with cron and it is simply too ugly.

Comment: Sorry, your intervals are so ugly. :-> Fork crontab and implement these advanced ranges or get an ups for your linuxbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find anything and couldn't get an answer here either, I resigned to write [a Python script](https://github.com/sbalmer/isittime) that understands the format I used in my question.

The script is run from Cron:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/isittime /etc/opening-hours && /sbin/open-lock || /sbin/close-lock
```